# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'bro' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to query MySQL database

```
statement = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "select * from file_post where gas_key='"+commun+"'";
fp =statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

where `commun` is

```
String commun= (String) session.getAttribute("commun");
```

I'm getting exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'bro' in 'where clause'

`bro` is the value of commun.

I also tried `PreparedStatement`, but that also gave me the same exception.

But when I make a query in MySQL command line:

```
select * from file_post where gas_key='bro';
```

It's perfect there and returns the exact data.

I can't figure out why it is giving me the exception when using the same query in a Java class.

Comment: Have you newly added this column in table. Commit it. It might be visible to SQL Developer of whatever IDE you are using in that particular session.

Comment: Be careful: building queries this way makes you vulnerable to SQL injection ([read more](http://stackoverflow.com/q/601300/182402)).

Comment: @AmitBhati sir, this column is not new

Comment: @WanderNauta sir, i m just a student n i m making this for a college project , so i m not so much concerned about security

Comment: @user3443275 And you're sure the person who is going to grade the project is as unconcerned? :)

Answer (score 1):

This exception happens normally when you don't match the `"`, to avoid problems like this use a `PreparedStatement`

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM file_post WHERE gas_key=?");
st.setString(1,commun);
rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Comment: sir i changed that to LIKE but its still throwing the same exception

Comment: sir i tried that too (mentioned in the question) but that also gave me the same exception

Comment: if so, you must found the mapped domain columns were does not match database ones

Comment: if all columns are maped and have the setters and getters, please show the mapping of your entities to check it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to print preparedStatement after setting variable...just to check what query is building...

System.out.println(preparedStatement);

and what is fp here? ResultSet?

Comment: yes sir fp is result set, n now the problem is solved , the problem was that the connections which i was getting from the connection pool  was not working correctly, when i cleaned my project it started working

Comment: its good you found problem...and solved on your own...and dont call me sir please.....!!